# Round permutation with relative forbidden position. The carousel problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Eight boys are seated around a carousel. In how many ways can they change seats so that each has a different boy in front of him?

Comment: This is a permutation problem with relative forbidden positions. I know how to solve this question when it's not a circular permutation problem, but for this problem I am a little confused

Answer (score 0):

A given carousel rotates in only one direction.

Seat boy $\#1$ anywhere, making him the reference point,
and "straighten" the circle thus: $1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-(1)$

Each permutation of the other $7$ will give a new arrangement,
so the answer is simply the same as seating around $8$ unnumbered seats, $7!$

If the seats are numbered (or have different animals, say),
$\#1$ has $8$ choices of seat, so the ans will be $8!$